# CSS box-shadow on all four sides

Tags: css

I have this class here and I using box-shadow which works fine, but it only shows the shadow on 2 sides, is there away to get the shadow on all four sides?

Thanks,
J

```
.contactBackground{
    background-color:#FFF;
    padding:20px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you set the offsets to zero, the shadow will be equal on all four sides.

```
.contactBackground{
    background-color:#FFF;
    padding:20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

### Box-Shadow

CSS3 box-shadow property has following attributes: ([W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp))

`box-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur spread color inset;`

In your example you're offsetting shadow by 10px vertically and horizontally.

Like in other comments set first two values to 0px in order to have even shadow on all sides.

### More on Shadows

The main prefix for shadow to support latest browsers is `box-shadow`.

There are 2 other ones that I recommend to use for older Mozilla and Webkit:

- `-moz-box-shadow`
- `-webkit-box-shadow`

Also, by using `rgba` instead of hex color value you can set the alpha/opacity of the shadow:
`box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);`

Answer (score 2):

Remove the offset definitions, and use only the blur radius (the third argument):

```
.contactBackground{
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try: box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px #000000;

Answer (score -1):

you need to specify box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 10px BLACK;

Right, Bottom, Left, Top

or you could say box-shadow-top: 10px BLACK; etc

Comment: if you are using chrome sometimes it helps to use the dev tools within. ctrl + shift + j to bring it up, it makes styling and javascript debugging so much easier

Comment: This answer is plain wrong: 1) box-shadow doesn't take Right Bottom, Left, Top 2) box-shadow-top, box-shadow-right, … doesn't exist in CSS 3) For other shorthand taking 4 values, the order is always: Top, Right, Left, Top (Memotechnic: TRBL= TRouBLe)